# Wordpress current taxonomy page

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a navigation menu where I show pages with special taxonomy, but I don't know how to make it marked as "current page"
My code:

```
    <div id="nav">

    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'page', 'kalba' => 'Lietuviu') );?>   
        <ul>

        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile;?>

       </ul>

   </div>
```